# Navigate to activity of UIPath is not working

Tags: uipath

#### UIPath advance certification

#### Navigate to activity of UIPath is not working

I am doing ui path advance certification. i am stuck in one step. my navigate to activity is not working whenever i navigate to page with respect to WIID to check client detail it doesn't work* . pls help me out.I successfully get WIID with category 5 but doesn't navigate to client detail page.

How to i navigate to client detail page?
[image]

Comment: have you tried recording step. hope that will work.

Comment: 1. Is your `Navigate to` inside an `attach browser`? Else you need to declare which browser you want to use 2. What is your `URL` if you print it out? Is it correct? 3. You don't need `[k[enter]]` at the end of `navigate to` because it automates go to the `URL`